# Forwarding props from parent to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components list of posts and when clicking on link on post card i'm entering into post.
I can't access props.postDetails in child component. When I console log the props, I have {history: {…}, location: {…}, match: {…}, staticContext: undefined} only this without props.postDetails.
Can somebody help?

Code for parent component is:

```
mport {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "./assets/images/logo.jpg";
import Post from './Post';


const Home = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getResults();
    },[]);

    const getResults =() => {
        fetch("https://blog-d8b04-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/posts.json")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {setPosts(data)});
    }

    const postsArr = [];
    Object.values(posts).forEach((post, key) => {
        postsArr.push(post);
    });

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="posts-container col-md-12">
                        <div className="row">
                            {
                                postsArr.map((post, key) => (
                                    <div className="col-md-4">
                                        <Link to={`/post/${key}`} >
                                            <div className="pic-wrapper">
                                                <img className="img-fluid" src={post.pic} alt={post.title}/>
                                            </div>
                                            <h4>{post.title}</h4>
                                            <Post postDetails={post}/>
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                ))
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Code for child component:

```
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";


const Post = (props) => {
    const {pic, title, author, description} = props.postDetails;
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="pic-wrapper">
                <img className="img-fluid" src={pic} alt={title}/>
            </div>
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <p>{author}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Post);
```

Comment: Is there a reason to wrap Post component 'withRouter'? Looks like the withRouter HOC isn't passing along the props from the parent.

Comment: Also without HOC withRouter is not forwarding, the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, without the HOC you won't get location, match, history props, however, if I'm reading your code correctly, it seems like you don't need to wrap your posts card withRouter. If you want a user clicking on the card to navigate to a details page, then you'd want two Routes; Home and PostDetail.

Comment: In the provided snippet I see absolutely no reason that `props.postDetails` wouldn't be defined.  Are you sure you are referencing the correct component? Can you provide a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue? What is the point of `postsArr`? Seems you could easily map the `posts` state directly. The `withRouter` also seems equally useless since it doesn't seem `Post` references any route props. Is this all your real, complete code?

Comment: @Drew Reese here is the reproduced code https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-lake-zt4et?file=/src/Post.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Ok, it's as I started to suspect. You are rendering a `Post` component in more than 1 place.

The issue here is that in `Home.js` you are passing a `postDetails` prop, (`<Post postDetails={post.pic} />`), but in `app.js` you are only passing the route props from `Route`, (`<Route path="/post/:postId" exact strict component={Post} />`). ***This*** `Post` component is the one triggering the error.

## Solution

An easy solution is to simply pass the `post` data along with the route transition.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/post/${key}`,
    state: {
      post
    }
  }}
>
  ...
  <Post postDetails={post.pic} />
</Link>
```

And access the route state on the receiving end in `Post`. Try to read the post details from props first, and if they is falsey (null or undefined) assume it was passed in route state and access it there.

```
const Post = (props) => {
  const { state } = props.location;
  const { pic, title, author, description } = props.postDetails ?? state.post;
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="pic-wrapper">
        <img className="img-fluid" src={pic} alt={title} />
      </div>
      <h4>{title}</h4>
      <p>{author}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Of course there is room to make this a bit more robust but this is a good start.

## Additional Suggestion

Instead of saving `post` state that isn't formed correctly for what/how you want to render it, you can transform the response data ***before*** saving it into state. This save the unnecessary step of transforming it every time the component rerenders.

```
const getResults = () => {
  setLoading(true);
  fetch(
    "https://blog-d8b04-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/posts.json"
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setPosts(Object.values(data));
      setLoading(false);
    });
};
```

Then map as per usual. Make sure to place the React key on the *outer-most* mapped element, the `div` in your case.

```
{posts.map((post, key) => (
  <div className="col-md-4" key={key}>
    ...
  </div>
))}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit forwarding-props-from-parent-to-child-component]

Comment: Thanks @Dreew Reese, maybe would be appropriate to load data from App.js - to use there useEffect hook, and than from  there to forward the props to Home route.

Comment: @Ivana Yes, IMO a more appropriate solution would be to store the posts in a common ancestor to all the components that would access them. For example, a React Context would help in this endeavor, it's lightweight.

Comment: @Dreew Reese, regarding you suggestion to load data from App.js and after that  you meant to forward data to child components - to Post.js like in this example same with <Link
                    to={{
                      pathname: `/post/${key}`,
                      state: {
                        post
                      }
                    }}
                  >? Or you meant something different?

Comment: @Ivana Hello, sorry, which suggestion are you referring to?

Comment: I understood that you would as suggestion fetch data in App.js  and then forward the data to child components, but I am curious about the way you would forward data to child components? With "to" property of <Link/> as you wrote in your example as we are iterating through array of posts, or how?

Comment: @Ivana I was just suggesting to "lift state up" and store the posts in the common ancestor. You have a route on `path="/post/:postId"` so that `Post` component will have a `postId` to reference a specific post. If you also pass the entire posts array to `Post` then it can resolve the specific post it needs to render..

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed an expected behaviour, because you are actually mapping what appears to be an empty array - see `postArr`; on your first render it will result as an empty array and since that's not a state, it will never re render your child component with the appropriate props.

I don't really see why you fetch the data, set them to your `posts` useState and then copy them over to a normal variable; Instead, remove your `postArr` and on the map replace it with your `posts` directly.

Since that's a state, react will listen to changes and rerender accordingly, fixing your problem

Comment: `postsArr` is computed every render cycle, so when `posts` state updates and triggers rerender, `postsArr` is also updated.

Comment: Actually you're right - So @Ivana, what if you add a console log just before your `Post` component? What does `post` returns at that point?